# How $u^{*}((A∩ E)∪(A∩ E^{c}∩ F))$ gets equal to $u^{*}(A∩ (E∪(E^{c}∩ F)))$

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to prove that union of two measurable sets is measurable, but got this step to be stucked up here, how L.H.S becomes equal to R.H.S, i want to sort out this technical step.

Answer (score 1):

Because $(A\cap E)\cup(A\cap E^{c}\cap F) =A\cap(E\cup(E^{c}\cap F))$

Notice that $(A\cap E)\cup(A\cap E^{c}\cap F)$ meaning set of elements in $A$ and $E$, or in $A$ and ($E^{c}\cap F)$, this is the same to say elements in $A$ and ( in $E $or in $E^{c}\cap F$), which is the right hand side.

If the sets are the same, they have the same measure (or outer measure, depending on what you mean by $\mu^*$) too.